# Use AJAX to load a page which itself contains an AJAX call

Tags: ajax

Is it possible to use AJAX to load a page, say pageB, into pageA. Where pageB uses AJAX to load some information into it from pageC?

The call on pageB doesn't seem to be made even though the call to pageB returns a ready state of 4.

Is it actually possible?

Thanks

Comment: Of course my friend. Use delegate event on the body which is listening on the domElement. It will listen even if a domElement is added after the whole document is ready. If it's not what you expected as answer tell us more !